# ¿Por qué me genera error implementar una foreign key (clave foranea) en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema cuando quiero implementar una `foreign key` en MySQL.

Me genera un error:

```
23:57:42    ALTER TABLE  `consultorio1`.`login` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_login_medic` FOREIGN KEY(`document_medic`) 
            REFERENCES `medico`(`document_medic`)   
            Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.406 sec
```

No sé por qué.

Comment: Has comprobado la coherencia de los datos?, es decir, que no tengas campos vacios en la FK, y que los datos existan en la tabla sobre la que quieres hacer FK

Comment: Pueden ser varias cosas, que los datos que ya existen no cumplan la FK que quires crear, que estás haciendo referencia a columnas de distinto tipo, que la columna no exista, etc. Por favor, adjunta la definición de las tablas y también indica sí estas tienen datos.

Answer (score 1):

Pueden ser varias cosas:

- Tipos distintos en los campos

  Este error indica que tu campo `fk_login_medic` tiene un tipo de datos distinto al `document_medic`.

  Por ejemplo, si `document_medic` es un `VARCHAR(255)` es necesario que `fk_login_medic` sea exactamente del mismo tipo.
- PK o Unique sobre el campo referenciado.

  El campo al que se hace referencia (`document_medic`) tiene que ser PK o Unique de la tabla `medico`.